# Persistent login using cookies and session variables

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, session-variables

I've been researching the best (and safest) ways to implement persistent logins on my website, and I've come up with the following:

When a user logs in, a cookie is created containing the user's ID/username, and a randomly generated number (token). The token is stored in a relational table along with the user ID/username. Every time a members-only page is loaded, this cookie is checked against the relational table, and if it exists *and* matches with the token, the login is valid and the page can load. If not, however, then the login is invalid, the cookie is destroyed, and the  user is prompted to log in.

I was thinking... to save on database access every single time a page is loaded, I could also have a session variable that lasts, say, 10 minutes, and is destroyed automatically when the browser closes. If the session is alive, then it's refreshed and the user can proceed. If the session expires, but the cookie is still valid, check the cookie, reset the token, store that new token in the database (while eliminating the old token, or storing it in an archives table for future reference), and reset the cookie using the new token value.

However, what would the session contain? And how could the session not simply be faked with some JavaScript? Perhaps the session contains a one-way encrypted hash? What would be used to generate that hash (user ID, etc.)?

I'm kind of stuck on where to go from here. I get the cookie stuff, but using temporary sessions (to avoid repeated calls to the database every single time a page is loaded) eludes me. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies should be fine (an alternative would be to store it in the HTTP header), however I don't see the need to store the username/ID in the cookie. The token itself should be enough. You can use a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) as a token. Store that along with the username and a last_access_timestamp in the database table. And only send the token (in a cookie or in the HTTP request header) on every request. That's enough for implementing sessions in my opinion.

A token is generated on a successful login of a user, stored in the database and passed to the user. Whenever a user accesses the webpage, the token is passen in the request and is validated. If valid the last_acces_timestamp is refreshed and the user can proceed. The lookup in the validation will be done by token and with the username you can do the authentication and authorizaton. If token is invalid or expired, forward the user to a login page.

Deleting expired sessions out of the db can be done periodically using a cron job or on creation of a new session.

For performance reason you might think about storing the session in a hashmap in memory. Since it might be costly to always update the database.

Also think about using HTTPS, to prevent people sniffing the token.

I have solved this the following way, few months ago:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829994/java-custom-session-implementation-expired-sessions

Comment: Just so I understand this properly... so when the user logs in, we store the user ID in cookie A, and a randomly-generated token in cookie B. We store the token in a database table alongside the user ID, so we can associate the two. Then, every time a members-only page is called up, cookies A and B are checked in the relational table to see if they match up (while at the same time updating the `time_last_accessed` field). If so, proceed; if not, cancel all the things. Is that about right?

Comment: No, you only need one cookie with the token. When a user logs in, pass him back the token in the response. The user will then send this token on every further request in a cookie. Based on the cookie alone you identify the user. Having the user id sent by the client does not add any additional security. Added security will be definitely added when doing the whole communication in HTTPS.

Comment: Ohhh! I get it now! It makes complete sense, having the token be the identifying bit of information. Thanks! And yes, I plan on using SSL for this.

Answer (score 2):

Usage of UUID is not recommended according to [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) it is stated that

> Do not assume that UUIDs are hard to guess; they should not be used as
>   security capabilities.

I would recommend combining and multiply all of the following information together into a hash with also encrypting it using a public key stored in your server.

- UserId (Or User UUID that was generated for each user while registration)
- **Encrypted** His/her password (considered as a private key for encryption per each user)
- Time stamp
- Client Operating System
- Client User Agent (Browser name)

For storing tokens, you could use either [memcache](http://memcached.org/) which is used heavily in big companies or [redis](http://redis.io) if you are focusing on persistence.

Keep sure that your cookies have the following attributes, for more info about [Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

- HTTP Only cookie
- Secure Cookie